# Array in Sum in Minimize - error "Part specification x[1] is neither a machine-sized integer"

Tags: mathematical-optimization, syntax

Help please

```
M = 10; 
z = Array[x, M]
```

> ```
> {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10]}
> ```

```
Gcd = Array[GCD, {M, M}];
Minimize[{ Sum[Gcd[[ x[i], x[j] ]], {i, M}, {j, M}],
           And @@ Table[1 <= x[k] <= M, {k, M}]},
         z,
         Integers]
```

> ```
> Part::pspec: Part specification x[1] is neither a machine-sized integer nor
> a list of machine-sized integers. >>_
> ```

---

Michael E2, thank you!

How to simplify the description a more complex function Sum?

```
M = 10; z = Array[x, M];
Gcd = Array[GCD, {M, M}];
Gcd1 = Table[GCD[a, b] + 1, {a, M}, {b, M}];

obj[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Sum[Gcd[[x[[i]], x[[j]]]]*Gcd1[[i, j]], {i, M}, {j, M}];

NMinimize[{obj[z], And @@ Table[1 <= x[k] <= M, {k, M}] && z ∈ Integers}, z]
```

And how to add a constraint alldifferent `x[i]`? (like AMPL-syntax "subject to all_diff {`i` in `1..M`, `j` in `1..M : i < j}: x[i] != x[j];`")

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: You can't beat `{1,1,1...1}`

Comment: @dio: I think what the OP is trying to do is minimize the given sum, where the `x[i]` are integers between 1 and 10. `Part` is getting unhappy at the fact that the `x[i]` are being treated as variables, and I don't know how to fix this, so I'd be interested to see what the correct syntax for this is.

Comment: What do you want to get with `Gcd[[x[i], x[j]]]`?

Comment: Alldifferent constraint I found: "And @@ Flatten[Table[x[i] != x[j], {i, M}, {j, i - 1}]]".

Answer (score 3):

One part of the problem is answered here: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).  You have to prevent the objective function from being evaluated before the `x[i]` are assigned numeric values.

The rest of the problem is, I think, that `Minimize` can't deal with this type of optimization, since the function cannot be analyzed symbolically, not without `Part` complaining at least.  (Perhaps someone will show us.)  However, `NMinimize` can deal with it, although it is not guaranteed to find the absolute minimum.

```
M = 10; z = Array[x, M];
Gcd = Array[GCD, {M, M}];
obj[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Sum[Gcd[[x[[i]], x[[j]]]], {i, M}, {j, M}];
NMinimize[{obj[z], And @@ Table[1 <= x[k] <= M, {k, M}] && z ∈ Integers}, z]

(*
  {100., {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 1, x[5] -> 1, 
    x[6] -> 1, x[7] -> 1, x[8] -> 1, x[9] -> 1, x[10] -> 1}}
*)
```

**Update**

This version of the objective function is about five or six times faster

```
obj[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Total[Gcd[[x, x]], 2]
```

For the second objective function, the analogous formula would be

```
obj[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Total[Gcd[[x, x]]*Gcd1, 2]
```

The speed up in `NMinimize` is about a factor of 2 or less.